# Proving vector properties

Tags: vectors

If $a,b,c$ are three vectors such that $a\times b = c$ and $b\times c = a$ what can be said about these vectors? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: c is perpendicular to a and b and a is perpendicular to b and c. That means a, b, c is pairwise perpendicular. 
Since a and b are orthogonal: $|c|=|a|\cdot |b|$
Since b and c are orthogonal: $|a|=|b|\cdot |c|$
These two equalities imply that $|b|=1$ and $|a|=|c|$.

Comment: Since they're orthogonal, they're also a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.